# Caching results from an API via drupal_http_request

Tags: views

I need to frequently access a restful API via drupal_http_request. I am doing this in a custom View. Is there anyway to cache this data so that I don't need to as frequently query the servers?

Comment: Which version of drupal are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Drupal 7

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Drupal's [cache API](https://drupal.org/node/145279) to store the response doing something like:

```
if (!cache_get('my_module_cache')) {
  $data = drupal_http_request($url, $options); // Add the param for the request to web service
  cache_set('my_module_cache', $data, 'cache',  REQUEST_TIME  + (3600 * 24 * 30 * 6)); // Stores in cache table and expires after 6 months
  return($data);
} else {
  $return = cache_get('my_module_cache');
  return($return->data);
}
```

Depending on how many times you need to get that cached value on same execution, you could also use [drupal_static()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_static/7).

On the example that I provided above, the expire policy is only based on time (6 months), in your case, you will need to analyse carefully the expire policy you are going to implement to expire/renew the cached value.

Lullabot has a great article about Drupal cache: [A beginner's guide to caching data](http://www.lullabot.com/blog/article/beginners-guide-caching-data)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I'll check it out and let you know if this solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it in a view, you can cache the view result  itself as long as you are not doing the `drupal_http_request` in the a template file or a preprocess function at the theme layer. You can do so by accessing the view's configuration, then clicking on cache and set it to a  desired duration Another way to do it is to use a wrapper function around your `drupal_http_request` and store the data using the drupal cache_api as gerzenstl suggested.